# Text content is not allowed inside a Target element

Tags: xamarin.forms, xcode9, visual-studio-mac

After upgrading visual studio for Mac and Xcode version 9, I keep getting an error loading my existing iOS projects.  The error is "Text content is not allowed inside a Target element".  I've verified that there is no text floating inside an element of the .csproj that's not valid.  I've tested the xml via https://www.xmlvalidation.com/index.php?id=1&L=0 and I get no errors returned.  Any ideas?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0">
   <PropertyGroup>
      <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">iPhoneSimulator</Platform>
      <ProjectGuid>{7657B753-FFF4-475C-AABD-5E9ACA147172}</ProjectGuid>
      <ProjectTypeGuids>{FEACFBD2-3405-455C-9665-78FE426C6842};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
      <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
      <RootNamespace>containerz.iOS</RootNamespace>
      <AssemblyName>containerz.iOS</AssemblyName>
      <IPhoneResourcePrefix>Resources</IPhoneResourcePrefix>
   </PropertyGroup>
   <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|iPhoneSimulator' ">
      <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
      <DebugType>full</DebugType>
      <Optimize>false</Optimize>
      <OutputPath>bin\iPhoneSimulator\Debug</OutputPath>
      <DefineConstants>DEBUG;ENABLE_TEST_CLOUD;</DefineConstants>
      <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
      <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
      <CodesignKey>iPhone Developer</CodesignKey>
      <MtouchDebug>true</MtouchDebug>
      <MtouchNoSymbolStrip>true</MtouchNoSymbolStrip>
      <MtouchFastDev>true</MtouchFastDev>
      <IOSDebuggerPort>30967</IOSDebuggerPort>
      <MtouchLink>None</MtouchLink>
      <MtouchArch>x86_64</MtouchArch>
      <MtouchHttpClientHandler>HttpClientHandler</MtouchHttpClientHandler>
      <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
   </PropertyGroup>
   <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|iPhone' ">
      <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
      <Optimize>true</Optimize>
      <OutputPath>bin\iPhone\Release</OutputPath>
      <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
      <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
      <CodesignKey>iPhone Developer</CodesignKey>
      <MtouchFloat32>true</MtouchFloat32>
      <CodesignEntitlements>Entitlements.plist</CodesignEntitlements>
      <MtouchLink>SdkOnly</MtouchLink>
      <MtouchArch>ARM64</MtouchArch>
      <MtouchHttpClientHandler>HttpClientHandler</MtouchHttpClientHandler>
      <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
   </PropertyGroup>
   <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|iPhoneSimulator' ">
      <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
      <Optimize>true</Optimize>
      <OutputPath>bin\iPhoneSimulator\Release</OutputPath>
      <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
      <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
      <CodesignKey>iPhone Developer</CodesignKey>
      <MtouchNoSymbolStrip>true</MtouchNoSymbolStrip>
      <MtouchLink>None</MtouchLink>
      <MtouchArch>x86_64</MtouchArch>
      <MtouchHttpClientHandler>HttpClientHandler</MtouchHttpClientHandler>
      <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
   </PropertyGroup>
   <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|iPhone' ">
      <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
      <DebugType>full</DebugType>
      <Optimize>false</Optimize>
      <OutputPath>bin\iPhone\Debug</OutputPath>
      <DefineConstants>DEBUG;ENABLE_TEST_CLOUD;</DefineConstants>
      <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
      <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
      <CodesignKey>iPhone Developer</CodesignKey>
      <DeviceSpecificBuild>true</DeviceSpecificBuild>
      <MtouchDebug>true</MtouchDebug>
      <MtouchNoSymbolStrip>true</MtouchNoSymbolStrip>
      <MtouchFastDev>true</MtouchFastDev>
      <MtouchFloat32>true</MtouchFloat32>
      <CodesignEntitlements>Entitlements.plist</CodesignEntitlements>
      <IOSDebuggerPort>49784</IOSDebuggerPort>
      <MtouchLink>SdkOnly</MtouchLink>
      <MtouchArch>ARM64</MtouchArch>
      <MtouchHttpClientHandler>HttpClientHandler</MtouchHttpClientHandler>
      <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
   </PropertyGroup>
   <ItemGroup>
      <Reference Include="System" />
      <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
      <Reference Include="System.Core" />
      <Reference Include="Xamarin.iOS" />
      <Reference Include="Xamarin.Forms.Core">
         <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.2.3.4.247\lib\Xamarin.iOS10\Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll</HintPath>
      </Reference>
      <Reference Include="Xamarin.Forms.Platform">
         <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.2.3.4.247\lib\Xamarin.iOS10\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.dll</HintPath>
      </Reference>
      <Reference Include="Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS">
         <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.2.3.4.247\lib\Xamarin.iOS10\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.dll</HintPath>
      </Reference>
      <Reference Include="Xamarin.Forms.Xaml">
         <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.2.3.4.247\lib\Xamarin.iOS10\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.dll</HintPath>
      </Reference>
   </ItemGroup>
   <ItemGroup>
      <ImageAsset Include="Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Contents.json" />
      <ImageAsset Include="Assets.xcassets\Contents.json" />
   </ItemGroup>
   <ItemGroup>
      <Folder Include="Resources\" />
   </ItemGroup>
   <ItemGroup>
      <InterfaceDefinition Include="LaunchScreen.storyboard" />
   </ItemGroup>
   <ItemGroup>
      <None Include="Info.plist" />
      <None Include="Entitlements.plist" />
      <None Include="packages.config" />
   </ItemGroup>
   <ItemGroup>
      <Compile Include="Main.cs" />
      <Compile Include="AppDelegate.cs" />
   </ItemGroup>
   <Import Project="..\containerz\containerz.projitems" Label="Shared" Condition="Exists('..\containerz\containerz.projitems')" />
   <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.CSharp.targets" />
   <Import Project="..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.2.3.4.247\build\portable-win+net45+wp80+win81+wpa81+MonoAndroid10+Xamarin.iOS10+xamarinmac20\Xamarin.Forms.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.2.3.4.247\build\portable-win+net45+wp80+win81+wpa81+MonoAndroid10+Xamarin.iOS10+xamarinmac20\Xamarin.Forms.targets')" />
</Project>
```

Comment: gotta see it to help...

Comment: Any code to show?

Comment: I added the .csproj code in the post

Comment: I uninstalled visual studio for Mac and reinstalled and I'm fine now.

Comment: Post your solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

key MtouchNoSymbolStrip is for debug only

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Answer (score 0):

The same issue happened to me. You can try the below steps:

1. Open the .csproj file in the text editor.
2. Fix the indentation of all the elements (give appropriate spacing to the parentand child elements).
3. Reopen your project and it will get loaded successfully.

The above steps worked for me.